# PyYAML: KeyError when trying to filter through multiple documents in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I've been sitting on this for several hours already, so any help would make this early year!

I'm trying to filter through `.xes.yaml` files which in most cases look like the picture provided at the very bottom of this question.
I am trying to loop through the files and filter for a specific trace, and when that trace is found, for specific instances of the events, which are the new documents in a yaml file (to my understanding).

Here is what I have so far:

```
directory = '/Users/xxx/Downloads/measure/lift'
# iterate over files in
# that directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if filename.endswith(".yaml"):
       log = open(f)
       for data in yaml.load_all(log, Loader=yaml.FullLoader):
            if data['log']['trace']['cpee:name'] == 'Specific trace':
                concept_instance = data['log']['trace']['concept:name'] # here is the number that corresponds to the concept:instance in events
            if data['event']['concept:instance'] == concept_instance and data['event']['cpee:lifecycle:transition'] == 'activity/receiving':
                print(data['event']['time:timestamp']) # as of right now, I only print the timestamp, because i need to make the other stuff work first
```

So, my problem is, that I get a KeyError for 'event' which I don't get.

```
(ba_gui) xxx@xxx-MBP xxx % /Users/xxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/xxx/bin/python /Users/xxx/xxx/overlay_graphs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/xxx/overlay_graphs.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xxx/xxx/overlay_graphs.py", line 21, in main
    if data['event']['concept:instance'] == concept_instance and data['event']['cpee:lifecycle:transition'] == 'activity/receiving':
KeyError: 'event'
```

Also, when I remove the last if-statement for 'event', I get a KeyError for 'log', however when I add  `break` after the if-statement, it works fine for some reason and it prints all concept_instances.

I would appreciate any help!!!! I'm getting mad looking at this any longer lol.
[image]

Comment: Some documents only contain `log` and some only contain `event`, so if you try to access both you will always get a `KeyError`. You need to do something like warp each part with `if 'log' in data`:` and `if 'event' in data` to do nothing if that key is missing.

Comment: @match: thanks for your comment! So i added these two additional if statements prior to the other ones and I think it works but now the code takes too long to compute the output. it takes 2 minutes to print the first process instance

Comment: @icbidt1018 Please don't ask additional questions in a comment. If you have a new question, just create another one, so that everyone sees it. And don't post screenshots of code, other people cannot copy code in images to reproduce your error.

Comment: @flyx wasn't a question, just a statement. and right, noted.